# Colorize Powershell Format-List output?

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to highlight a single output field in my Powershell commandlet with some color.  Seems simple and perhaps the answer is it cannot be done in a simple fashion.  If that is the case, that is fine, just wanted to see if anyone knew of any easy way to accomplish the desired output.

What I am trying to run (Using Hashtable to attempt to add color):

```
Get-Mailbox -PublicFolder | Sort Name | FL @{Name='Mailbox Name';Expression={write-host -NoNewline $_.Name -ForegroundColor Green}},Proh*,Issue*,MaxReceiveSize,MaxSendSize,UseDatabaseQ*,Database
```

In the output you will notice the write-host is putting the name of the mailbox before it's label.
[Code with Hashtable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDuzy.png)

Now to contrast, if I avoid attempting to add color (Simplified code without the Hashtable):

```
Get-Mailbox -PublicFolder | Sort Name | FL Name,Proh*,Issue*,MaxReceiveSize,MaxSendSize,UseDatabaseQ*,Database
```

Everything comes out perfectly formatted.
[Simplified code without Hashtable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMI8b.png)

Is there a way to get the standard FL formatting but adding color to that one output?

**Responses:**

To Theo, Thank you that worked!  Appreciate you adding the multi color option.

To JS2010, Thank you for your suggestion.  I am, unfortuntely, not getting the desired output.  As stated below, I am on PS 4.0 currently(plans to upgrade soon).
[image]

To Øyvind, similar to the issue seen in JS2010s code.  Here is what I am getting from your suggestion.  Possibly again a versioning issue.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by first capturing the `Format-List` output as string in a variable, split it at the newlines and output each line yourself like this:

```
$result = Get-Mailbox -PublicFolder | Sort-Object Name | 
          Format-List Name,Proh*,Issue*,MaxReceiveSize,MaxSendSize,UseDatabaseQ*,Database | 
          Out-String
```

If you only want to color the one property:

```
switch -regex ($result -split '\r?\n') {
    '^Name\s*:' { 
            $label,$value = $_ -split ':',2 
            Write-Host ($label + ":") -NoNewline
            Write-Host $value -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    default { $_ }
}
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to be able to color more properties, create a hashtable with the property names and the colors to use:

```
$propertyColors = @{
    Name        = 'Green'
    MaxSendSize = 'Cyan'
}

switch ($result -split '\r?\n') {
    default { 
        if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)) {
            $label,$value = $_ -split ':',2 
            if ($propertyColors.ContainsKey($label.Trim())) {
                Write-Host ($label + ":") -NoNewline
                Write-Host $value -ForegroundColor $propertyColors[$label.Trim()]
            }
            else { $_ }
        }
        else  { $_ }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help Theo, your suggestion worked for me.  Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with regex, is there a way for me to try and break this code down and understand what your code is doing?

Comment: @MichaelB. Sure. the split on `'\r?\n'` simply splits the multiline text on newline characters whether it is in Windows format (CRLF) or *nix format (LF) to get an array of text lines. `'^Name\s*:'` is a test that says: From the start of the line (^) check if it begins with 'Name', followed by zero or more whitespace characters (`\s*`), followed by a colon (:). If that is the case, do what is between the curly brackets. Otherwise, do whatever is specified after the `default` switch option (in this case, just output the line as-is)

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt.  If you want to go through the trouble.  There's probably a powershell module that does color (Pansies?).  Write-host doesn't write to standard output, and redirection takes away the color.

```
$e = [char]0x1b # escape
[pscustomobject]@{a = "$e[32mhi$e[0m"} | format-table
```

Output (pretend the 'hi' is green):

```
a
-
hi
```

Comment: JS2010, thanks for your assistance.  Does your code work in PS 4.0?  I did not get the desired output.  We are planning to upgrade to 5.1 in the coming months.  However for now I am working with 4.0.  Not sure if that is playing into why my output is different than yours.

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$e = [char]0x1b # escape
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>[pscustomobject]@{a = "$e[32mhi$e[0m"} | format-table

a
-
←[32mhi←[0m

Answer (score 0):

js2010's tip and variable interpolation will do the trick!

```
$e = [char]0x1b # escape
Get-Mailbox -PublicFolder | Sort Name | FL @{Name='Mailbox Name';Expression={"$e[32m$($_.Name)$e[0m"}},Proh*,Issue*,MaxReceiveSize,MaxSendSize,UseDatabaseQ*,Database
```